# How can I read the coordinates of a button?

Tags: objective-c

```
UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
contentView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"]];
self.view = contentView;
[contentView release];
[contentView addSubview:scrollView];

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1800,480);
UIScrollView* tscrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){.origin.x = 0.0f, .origin.y = 0.0f, .size.width = 320.0f, .size.height = 5480.0f}];
tscrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1800,192);

Object1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:1];  
Object1.frame = CGRectMake(383, 250, 256, 192);  
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"02_1024_768.jpg"];
[Object1 setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//[self.view addSubview:Object1];
[scrollView addSubview:Object1];

Object5 = [UIButton buttonWithType:1];
Object5.frame = CGRectMake(1487, 250, 256, 192);
UIImage *buttonImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"p5.jpg"];
[Object5 setBackgroundImage:buttonImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[scrollView addSubview:Object5];

UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(400, 100, 200, 200)];
[myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
myLabel.text = @"Button1 is in range";
[myLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[myLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

NSLog(@"x = %d",Object1.center.x);
position = CGPointMake(0,0);
Object1.center = CGPointMake(Object1.center.x+position.x,Object1.center.y+position.y);

if((Object1.center.x >341) && (Object1.center.x < 597)){
    [myLabel setHidden:NO];
}
else {
    [myLabel setHidden:YES];
}
[self.view addSubview:myLabel];
```

Here is the code, but seems that the x coordinates always equals to 0. Could some1 tell me why and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try printing with %f, coordinates in Cocoa are CGFloats.

Comment: Could you explain what it is you are trying to do, it isn't clear where you are seeing the 0 value or what the point of this is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSLog(@"x=%f",Object1.center.x);
```

coordinates are float value and you print like int so you get 0. i check your code in project

Comment: Hi Abzal, thank you for your reply. I am now able to read the value although the if statement is still not working even if the x value is 511. Should I move the if statement out of the viewdidload loop? If so, please let me know which method should I use. Thanks again.

Comment: first tell me what you want to do? in my case i go in if statement

Comment: Sure, actually I want to hide the text when the button is not in range and vice versa. Now all the code is in viewdidload loop which might cause problems. But I have no idea which method should I use. Maybe you can give me some suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: then why not ask other question?

Comment: see this:http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-learning-about-touch-events-basic-game-animation/

Comment: Well, the website you sent mainly taught me how to jump from different views. But still I have no idea which method should I use in my case...

Comment: Thanks, I am now moving the if statement to NSTimer loop which read the value every 0.5s, but the value I got doesn't change according to the swiping. Did I use the wrong method of reading the coordinates?